# Hyperledger Fabric Custom chaincode invoke failed

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to run a custom chaincode. I was able to deploy it successfully but when I run the invoke command using:

```
peer chaincode invoke -n mycc -c '{"Args":["write","hello_world", "200"]}'
```

Facing this error message:

> Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error
>   deploying         chaincode: Failed to launch chaincode spec(Could not
>   get deployment transaction from LCCC for mycc - Error deploying
>   chaincode: Transaction or query returned with failure: transaction not
>   found default/mycc)

Logs after successful deployment of chaincode on peer (Running peer in DEV mode):

```
13:48:06.320 [shim] INFO : Chaincode log level not provided; defaulting to: DEBUG
13:48:06.320 [shim] DEBU : Peer address: 0.0.0.0:7051
13:48:06.321 [shim] DEBU : os.Args returns: [./chaincode_start]
13:48:06.323 [shim] DEBU : Registering.. sending REGISTER
13:48:06.324 [shim] DEBU : []Received message REGISTERED from shim
13:48:06.325 [shim] DEBU : []Handling ChaincodeMessage of type: REGISTERED(state:created)
13:48:06.325 [shim] DEBU : Received REGISTERED, ready for invocations
13:54:16.458 [shim] DEBU : [lccc]Received message INIT from shim
13:54:16.458 [shim] DEBU : [lccc]Handling ChaincodeMessage of type: INIT(state:established)
13:54:16.458 [shim] DEBU : Entered state init
13:54:16.458 [shim] DEBU : [lccc]Received INIT, initializing chaincode
13:54:16.461 [shim] DEBU : [lccc]Inside putstate
13:54:16.461 [shim] DEBU : [lccc]Sending PUT_STATE
13:54:16.462 [shim] DEBU : [lccc]Received message RESPONSE from shim
13:54:16.462 [shim] DEBU : [lccc]Handling ChaincodeMessage of type: RESPONSE(state:init)
13:54:16.462 [shim] DEBU : [lccc]before send
13:54:16.462 [shim] DEBU : [lccc]after send
13:54:16.464 [shim] DEBU : [lccc]Received RESPONSE, communicated (state:init)
13:54:16.464 [shim] DEBU : [lccc]Received RESPONSE. Successfully updated state
13:54:16.464 [shim] DEBU : [lccc]Init succeeded. Sending COMPLETED
13:54:16.464 [shim] DEBU : [lccc]Move state message COMPLETED
13:54:16.464 [shim] DEBU : [lccc]Handling ChaincodeMessage of type: COMPLETED(state:init)
13:54:16.465 [shim] DEBU : [lccc]send state message COMPLETED
```

Any pointer on where I am going wrong would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kindly include the command used to deploy the chaincode. I am wondering whether you did indeed name the chaincode as "mycc" with the -n switch

Comment: This is the deploy command: peer chaincode deploy -n mycc -c '{"Args":["init","100"]}'

Answer (score 0):

A couple of modifications to the invoke syntax might help.

- If security is enabled, then a -u parameter should be used to specify a user who has already enrolled.
- For the -n parameter, the chaincode ID could be tried rather than the chaincode name.

Example syntax for an invoke is included under the “Testing and verifying your local network” heading at https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmblockchain/fabric-peer/.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was able to invoke the chaicode after I restarted the peer container. Again it's been intermittent for me. If I stop the peer and restart it back and try the command, I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that you set environment variables before running this command, once you entered the peer container afresh you need to do that. Also, when invoking chaincode, you need to pass a few flags, and its options accordingly.

Try command like this:

```
***peer chaincode invoke -o <orderer-string>:<port> --tls --cafile <permissions-path-which-is-.pem-file> -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["write","hello_world", "200"]}'***
```